# How to visit a site hosted by my virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-networking, django, bitnami

I'm trying to learn Django. I installed a Bitnami Django stack on a Virtualbox with Ubuntu 64.

My issue is that, when I run the server, I have no idea how to visit the web page from my host computer (Windows 7, 64).

Do i need to do some complex configuration in order to visit the hosted website ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the network adapter configuration of the virtual machine.

The easier case is if you have a bridged adapter so the virtual machine guest looks like just another machine in your network. If the guest is configured to receive an IP address via DHCP (pretty much default setup), just point your browser at `http://IP-ADDRESS-OF-GUEST/` and it should work.

If you have NAT-ed network adapter in your virtual machine, it means it works as if the guest OS was sitting behind a router. It is still possible to access the web server, but you need to do the „dreaded” port forward.

Read up on the VB manual ([Configuring Port Forwarding with NAT](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward)). But as an example here is a command-line that creates a forwarded port (VM name is your virtual machine's name):

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "guesthttp,tcp,,80,,80"
```

Now you should reach your webserver at `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/` or even `http://IP-ADDRESS-OF-HOST/` (but the latter requires your host firewall is configured to receive traffic on port 80).

There is also a graphical way to do the port forward, you can find it in the configuration section of a NAT-ted virtual adapter. Quite straightforward to set up, but you can refer to this [HTG Article](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) on the subject.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer, but i'm going to post a simplified direct answer to my problem here : in virtualbox configuration, change the network access mode to "Bridged adaptor" instead of "NAT". After that, your machine will show up on your router as a seperate entity with its own IP adress which you can now visit directly.

Comment: Thanks! Though I think it is still worth to investigate the port forwarding technique with NAT, (or at least the graphical configurator), because you can host a safe service on your machine. It looks like your host OS had the service but in fact it is the guest. You can create a snapshot of the VM, and if the service gets corrupted, just restore it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a windows specific thing than Ubuntu. If it were a linux box that hosted your virtual machine you could do port forwarding by
`ssh user@<ip of virtual machine> -L9999:localhost:<port hosted on>`
This way you could go you http:// localhost:9999 and you would be at the site hosted on your virtual machine. 
Sorry I don't know how to do this from windows since I'm not sure how putty might handle this =\

Though I do know that when a machine has jenkins which hosts a web interface on port 8080 as long as you are on the same lan you can go to .local:8080 so maybe something like that would work. To know your avahi name or just to set it manually edit /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf and change the host-name line to equal whatever name you want it and run `sudo service avahi-daemon restart`

Also make sure when setting host-name to leave no space on either side of the = sign